# DragDropg different image from picturebox

Tags: c#

I have a project where I'm building a wardrobe and I have all the items that I want to put in it (for example shelves, drawers, etc...)
I have a Picture-box of a shelf but when I drag to the picture-box of the wardrobe another Picture-box of a shelf go to the position I dragged not the Picture-box from the icon.

Comment: Please rewrite your question so that it's clear what you're asking. It's impossible to answer your question in its current form.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.  If you were describing a problem, you forgot the relevant code.

Comment: what happens is when i drag the picture box A to the picture box B the picture box B is replaced by the picture box A.What im asking is,how i make so picture box B becomes B and A.